# BigCommerce Requirements to "Join the Technology Partner Program"

Tags: bigcommerce

I want to write an app for BigCommerce.
On the [BigCommerce developer website](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/), it says

"Before you begin, you’ll need a sandbox store. BigCommerce offers app developers free sandbox stores through its Technology Partner Program. To get your sandbox store, apply to become a BigCommerce Technology Partner. To be approved as a partner, you will need:

- A website.
- The ability to support users of your app."

I have written code to modify themes using trial stores in the past without being a partner. (That is not what I am trying to do here, I did that in the past. I am trying to write an app, ANY app. I made the statement about modifying themes with a trial store to emphasize the fact that I know that I can do that and I am assuming that the sandbox store has other capabilities like the ability to access the control panel code.) As far as I can see, an app will need to integrate with the control panel code that I cannot see from just having a store. So, I am assuming that the sandbox store issued when approved as a partner will have this capability.

I sent an email to BigCommerce asking about the approval requirements and their reply was this.

“you must prove that you are an application developer. This consists of a website where you showcase the functionality and current companies that are possibly using your app.

If you have issue with the requirement to be approved as a partner you will need to speak with the team that does the approvals. Partnersupport@bigcommerce.com”

This reply came from appstore@bigcommerce.com. Why wasn't my email forwarded to Partnersupport@bigcommerce.com to begin with so I could get a more comprehensive answer? I did forward it to them and I am still waiting for an answer.

I am confused about this requirement.
I want to write a BigCommerce app. Are they saying that I cannot write a BigCommerce app unless I have written a BigCommerce app before? Are they saying that I have to have written other apps in general? If I write a great app, why would it matter if it is my first?

After I write the app, I can set up a webpage for it and submit it for approval.

How can I "showcase the functionality and current companies that are possibly using your(my) app" when it is an app specifically written for BigCommerce?

I cannot write the app unless I understand how to integrate it with BigCommerce.
As far as I can see, I cannot understand how to integrate it with BigCommerce unless I am a partner.

Am I missing something here?
Is there some other way to approach this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not BigCommerce support. Contact them directly to ask questions about specific requirements they might have or why your email was not routed in a way you think is correct. This site is for programming related questions. We're not vendor support.

Comment: @Ken This question is about programing. It is about how to start writing apps for BigCommerce. I added the part about the email routing to emphasize the fact that BigCommerce does not respond with coherent answers. That is why I am asking for help from someone that may know the real answer. Also, if you look at BigCommerce's support page, https://developer.bigcommerce.com/support/, there is no where else to turn. They direct you here.

Comment: There isn't a way to modify the theme programmatically at this time. Also, you should contact appstore@bigcommerce.com with these questions.

Comment: @Alyss I do not understand why you are saying that "There isn't a way to modify the theme programmatically". This question is about modifying the functionality of the control panel which is exactly what apps do. Also, I have contacted BigCommerce, hence my statement "I sent an email to BigCommerce asking about the approval requirements and their reply was this." Your reply is typical of what I get from BigCommerce and the SOLE reason for this post. I am seeking a real answer from someone that does not work at BigCommerce.

Comment: Well since I work at BigCommerce, I'll stop trying to answer :p

Comment: To be clear, I meant there wasn't a way to change the theme via the API. If you are using an oauth app, you can install/access an app from the control panel. You might want to clean up your question given the interpretation issues.

Comment: @Alyss My question has been updated.

Comment: So it seems like you have some confusion around acquiring a sandbox account and consequently how you will show your app being functional. Is that accurate?

Comment: @Alyss More of a lack of information than confusion. Also, I have not written the app. I cannot write it until I see what code I need to manipulate.

Comment: To be clear, there is no way to see the control panel core application code, even if you have a partner sandbox.

Comment: @Alyss Then how does one do it? To be clear, let's take a very simple example. When I enter the weight into a product, I see either pounds or ounces as the unit of measure. There is an option in the store setup to switch it to pounds or ounces, but what if I want to display both pounds and ounces? I would need to write code to add a form and do a calculation. Where do I start?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127072/discussion-between-alyss-and-matt).

Comment: No need to be rude Matt, especially when some of the smartest folks at BigCommerce are taking time to try to help you despite your hostility. That said, all of your answers can be found already both on this website and the BC API documentation. The process you are referring to only applies if you want to release your app in the app store - you can still develop an app without going through the partner registration process. BC is a closed source platform similar to Shopify (opposite to WordPress) so you will not have access to modify the platform/CP code. Instead, you have acess to ...

Comment: ...you have access to their REST API, which allows modification to certain resources and scopes defined by the API documentation. If you want to jump right into developing an app, then all you need is an active BigCommerce store (a trial works) and then create `Legacy API Credentials`, which can be created within the CP under System settings I believe. Once you have those credentials, you can connect to their API via Basic Auth and begin writing programs to interface with your store (this is a standarized process on how all web API's work and function).

Comment: I recommend going to GitHub and search for "bigcommerce" followed by your preferred programming language (PHP, python, ruby, node, etc). This will give you access to what is essentially an SDK to allow you to quickly begin writing programs for your store.

Comment: @root Rude and hostile, I was just commending myself on how well I was handling these crazy responses . . . lol. I understand what you are saying, but I guess I'm missing the big picture.  I have figured out how to send an API call to BigCommerce with credentials to do something simple like read an order that is in a json array format. I know it's possible to send an API call to modify an order or a customer, but those things are just data in a database.

Comment: I want to add an input form to a product in the CP and use the data to let's say select only FedEx at checkout. From what you are saying, I can do this serverside. Now that you have told me that everything has to be done with API, if this is true, then maybe I should post a specific question. I don’t know where to start.

Answer (score 2):

Sr Marketplace Mgr for BigCommerce here. I think there are a few items of clarification I can offer:

- You do not have to have an existing BigCommerce app to be approved for a partnership. You do however need some evidence of your existing work. If you don't have a portfolio, website, or other examples of your development work, it's difficult for our Partners team to determine if you're a qualified developer.
- Partner apps will not have access to modify the BC control panel or core code. Apps must use our public APIs to work with a BC user's data or settings. Any settings that are in the CP but not in our APIs can't be modified directly via an app.
- Any storefront changes - such as an edit to a BC theme to display weight in two different units - would have to be done using HTML/CSS/JS in the theme itself. We don't have an API for programmatically changing a storefront theme at this time.
- If any of your questions for BigCommerce involve your app or app development, you'll need to direct them to my team at appstore@bigcommerce.com. Directing questions regarding your app to partnersupport@bigcommerce.com will be forwarded to my team. That channel is primarily for questions around the Partners program in general, and won't be able to provide detailed support on the app developer program.

Hopefully this clears up some of your confusion, please reach out to me at appstore@bigcommerce.com and I'll be happy to respond myself if you need more info.

Cheers - John

Comment: No, this does not clear up anything. 1) Why is it difficult for your Partners team to determine if I'm a qualified developer? If I submit a really great app that functions well, isn't that enough proof? 2) "Apps must use our public APIs to work with a BC user's data or settings." Ok, so how would I get started with my example about the weight?

Comment: 3) There was no mention of storefront changes, was this just something that you threw in?  The weight example is about entering it in the product, not the store front. 4) Communicating with your team by sending and receiving an email through appstore@bigcommerce.com would take an extremely long time to have a simple conversation. Why is it that i cannot talk to someone on the phone?

Comment: Ok, let me ask you this . . . can I write, practice writing, or learn how to write a BigCommerce app without being a partner?